# Codeception accessing Chosen select

Tags: php, testing, codeception

When using Chosen the select element gets hidden and can't be selected by codeception. I tried it like this:

```
$I->selectOption('form select[name="jform[plugin_id]"]', array('value' => '10054'));
```

or this:

```
$I->selectOption('div#jformplugin_id_chzn .chzn-results', 'Optimizer');
```

or this:

```
$I->click(['css' => 'div#jformplugin_id_chzn']); 
$I->fillField(['xpath' => '//div[@id="jformplugin_id_chzn"]/div/div/input'], 'Optimizer');
$I->click(['xpath' => '//div[@id="jformplugin_id_chzn"]/div/ul/li[1]']);
```

Nothing really works.

---

Here is the HTML-Code i'm trying to access:

```
    <select id="jformplugin_id" name="jform[plugin_id]" style="display: none;">
        <option value="" selected="selected">- Selection -</option>
        <option value="10037">test3</option>
        <option value="10038">test2</option>
        <option value="10054">Optimizer</option>    
        <option value="10058">test1</option>
    </select>

   <div class="chzn-container chzn-container-single chzn-container-single-nosearch" title="" id="jformplugin_id_chzn"><a class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1"><span>- Selection -</span><div><b></b></div></a>
    <div class="chzn-drop">
        <div class="chzn-search"><input type="text" readonly=""></div>
        <ul class="chzn-results">
            <li class="active-result result-selected" style="" data-option-array-index="0">- Selection -</li>
            <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">test3</li>
            <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="2">test2</li>
            <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="3">Optimizer</li>
            <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="4">test1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Try something like this:*
$I->executeJS("document.querySelector('#jformplugin_id').style.display = block;");

Answer (score 0):

You can't use any of your methods on invisible elements. Only way to change select value is to execute Javascript, something like this:

```
$I->executeJS('document.getElementById("jformplugin_id").value = 10054;');
```

By the way on big selects with lot of options selecting value with Javascript is lot of faster then using built in method selectOption.